# Audit too obvious when review queue is filtered

Tags: bug, review-queues, review-audits

I have been doing review for close votes and I filtered to *primarily opinion-based*. I stumbled upon one question, unfortunately the screen capture doesn't say it perfectly:

[image]

but before I passed it, it said:

> This question has been flagged as: *unclear what you're asking* (more)

and that's all. It is fairly usual that when you filter to specific queue you get questions that were flagged for more than the reason you filtered. **BUT** this was quite obvious, as it had nothing else in the description and my filter was on. When I saw it I felt suspicious:

[image]

And it turned out I was right and it *was* an audit.

Is it deliberate (feature), or overlooked detail in the query for pulling audits (bug)?

Comment: Audits are meant to make sure that you're paying attention and not just clicking accept/reject without reading the post. If you noticed the vote reason, I think it's fair to say you're paying enough attention.

Comment: Well, yes I guess. It just surprised me and I felt like...maybe it could be even better.

Comment: Thanks @Louis, closing it down.